# Getting a specific sequence of frames from video in python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, opencv3.0

I need to extract a specific sequence of frames from video, for example I want

to extract every 10th frame for example (frame_1,frame_10,frame_20,...). I'm

using below code but it extracts all frame , any idea how to do this ?

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:

   cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
   success,image = vidcap.read()

count += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add another solution, you can use [set](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c) function  and [`CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da6223452891755166a4fd5173ea257068) prperty id to get the frame 10 frames later like this:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
   cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
   success,image = vidcap.read()
   count += 1
   vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, count * 10 )
```

This may give you an advantage in performance over the other answer, since it will not read each frame, but if it is a video from a camera, I think this solution will not do anything and the other one will.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [modulo](https://betterexplained.com/articles/fun-with-modular-arithmetic/) of the framecount:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
frame = 0 #after first frame read, so frame 0 will be saved, next every 10th
success = True
while success:

   if frame % 10 == 0:
       cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
       count += 1
   success,image = vidcap.read()
   frame += 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot @J.D and @ api55